# Yup conditional validation based on a a non field value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I am trying to create a yup schema where based on a variables value the schema changes slightly. In my case depending on the value of prop `myCondition` I need to make a field as required. I would like to know if there is any better way I can achieve the same using Yup. Here's my current code structure that works:

```
// config.js
const COMMON_SCHEMA = {
  str1: yup
    .string()
    .nullable()
    .required('Please input str1'),
  str3: yup
    .string()
    .nullable()
};
const VALIDATION_SCHEMA_1 = yup.object().shape({
  ...COMMON_SCHEMA,
  str2: yup.string().nullable(),
});

const VALIDATION_SCHEMA_2 = yup.object().shape({
  ...COMMON_SCHEMA,
  str2: yup
    .string()
    .nullable()
    .required('Please input str2'),
});

const SCHEMAS = {
  VALIDATION_SCHEMA_1,
  VALIDATION_SCHEMA_2
}
export default SCHEMAS;
```

the following is how I conditionally choose different schemas:

```
// app.js
import SCHEMAS from './config';
...

<Formik
  validationSchema={
    this.props.myCondition === true
      ? SCHEMAS.VALIDATION_SCHEMA_1
      : SCHEMAS.VALIDATION_SCHEMA_2
  }
>
...
</Formik>
```

I feel like I can achieve whatever I am doing above in an easier way with `yup`. One of the approaches I tried was to pass in the prop `myCondition` into config file and work with it's value by using `yup.when()` but `when` only works if the value you want to use is also a part of the form so I couldn't achieve the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be achieved by the following way:

You can wrap your schema in a function and pass your conditional prop:

```
const wrapperSchema = (condition) => 
  Yup.object().shape({
    ...COMMON_SCHEMA,
    str2: yup.string()
     .when([], {
       is: () => condition === true,
       then: yup.string().nullable(),
       otherwise: yup.string().required('Please input str2'),
     }),
  });
```

Please note that first param of when is a required param, you can also pass e.g. `["title", "name"]` where title and name can be your field values, and you can retrieve and use them in `is` callback, in the same order, if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally add validation directly in the validationSchema, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56216753/8826314

Edited to add, you can include your value in the initial form, so that you can do the `when` check against that field. For example:

```
<Formik 
  initialValues={
    ...,
    str2
  }
  validationSchema={
    ...,
    str2: yup.object().when('str2', {
      is: str2 => condition check that returns boolean,
      then: Yup.string().nullable(),
      otherwise: Yup.string().nullable().required('Please input str2')
    })
}
>
...
</Formik>
```