# Conditionally validating Formik field with YUP via a state hook?

Tags: react-hooks, formik, yup

I have searched around, not sure if this is possible. Essentially I am wanting to validate a formik form with YUP using a state hook that is not a form value.

```
 validationSchema={Yup.object({
          comments: Yup.string()
              .when(approvalState, {
                is: false,
                then: Yup.string().required('Comments are required when denying an approval.'),
              }),
        })}
```

Here is the form field, it is essentially a text box:

Here is the submit button, which changes the state value to true:

```
<button className='buttonPrimary' type='submit' onClick={()=> setApprovalState(true)} disabled={formik.isSubmitting}>Approve</button>
```

Here is the other button which also submits, changes the state value to false:

```
<button className={`buttonSecondary ${styles.marginRight}`} type='submit' onClick={()=> setApprovalState(false)} disabled={formik.isSubmitting}>Deny</button>
```

The state value updates fine, any way to conditionally validate the textbox as required based on a piece of state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution will work if `approvalState` is in values of formik:

```
Yup.object({
  comments: Yup.string()
               .when('approvalState', { // Change approvalState to string
                 is: false,
                 then: Yup.string().required('Comments are required when denying an approval.'),
               }),
})
```

Alternatively you can do:

```
Yup.object({
  comments: approvalState
              ? Yup.string()
              : Yup.string().required('Comments are required when denying an approval.')

})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use state hook and render conditionally. please have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/54919273/10154990