# Conditional yup validation based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I have this validation:

```
    ticket: yup
      .number()
      .required(I18n.t("is_required"))
      .when([], {
        is: () => {
          return timeFramedExperience;
        },
        then: yup.number().nullable(),
      }),
    max_p: yup
      .number()
      .required(I18n.t("is_required"))
      .when([], {
        is: () => {
          return timeFramed;
        },
        then: yup.number().nullable(),
      }),
```

`timeFramed` is a react hook state set to true. I want these fields, `max_p` and `ticket` to not be required when `timeFramed` is true.

but, on submit, I get this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394391/conditional-validation-in-yup) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919228/conditional-validation-with-yup-and-formik).

Comment: in my case I want to use a react hook state to decide on the condition, not a form registered field

Comment: In that case you could add the state as a field, or use `yup context`. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-yup-resolver-forked-z4s98k?file=/src/App.js) is an example that might help you. See [yup documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup/tree/v0.32.11#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema).

Comment: I'll check that. I was able to solve it creating two schemas and concatenating them based on that condition

Comment: @c0m1t Incorrect. Your references are questions on conditionals using other form fields. As the OP suggested, (and what I'm also trying to achieve) is conditionals based on outside variables, such as state.

Comment: @anastymous I have provided a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-yup-resolver-forked-z4s98k?file=/src/App.js) in the comment above which uses yup context. In the provided code, `checked` is a state variable that is passed as a context to yup. `checked` is not part of the yup schema or form. It can be a variable sourced from props or state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use different schemas as OP mentioned:

```
   condition ? : schema1 : schema2
```

2. Use yup context:

```
   yup
   .string()
   .when("$condition", (condition, schema) =>
     condition ? schema : schema.required()
     // Here `condition` is passed as context to yup.
   )
```

3. Use a hidden field or add the state to the form somehow.

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-conditional-validation-xd2cjy) which uses `react-hook-form` and `yup` to validate and has implemented the 3 solutions mentioned above.

If your state may change during the time user is filling in the form, be careful about calling `trigger`. Calling `trigger` before your state updates in the next render could lead to bugs.